# Webbrowser control not loading elements on screen without firing any events

Tags: c#, events, controls, webbrowser-control

I've built an app running a CRM website. Everything seems to be working fine except one thing.

When I click on a certain button on screen, it registers the mouseclick but never "load" anything. It display a new html popup on screen, like a div or frame on top of everything but the webbrowser is not seeing it as navigating or anything.

I checked all the events associated with webbrowser and nothing is firing but a new "window" appear on top of everything on the page.

I tried : navigated, documentcompleted, ProgressChanged, StatusTextChanged and DocumentTitleChanged but nothing is registering changes in the webpage.
 And I really need to know when the popup and elements are loaded so my app can do some changed...

Comment: Please post a sample code or a url.

Comment: @Guillanume, The action may use AJAX request.  Can it be possible to give your website URL.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible for me to post an URL because the site is locked behind a gateway site. But thanks for the suggestion about ajax request, i'll look into that